# Connectivity between two linux hosts

Tags: linux, networking

We have two CentOS VMs on one ESX server. IP and route configuration is done

Connectivity check between the VMs using `netcat` fails

On VM1

```
[root@vm1 ~]# nc -4lv 7001
Ncat: Version 7.70 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Listening on 0.0.0.0:7001
```

On VM2

```
[root@vm2 ~]# nc -4v 10.85.41.126 7001
Ncat: Version 7.70 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: No route to host.
```

But ping works

```
[root@vm2 ~]# ping 10.85.41.126
PING 10.85.41.126 (10.85.41.126) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.85.41.126: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.216 ms
```

Information for VM1

```
[root@vm1 ~]# ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens192: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:50:56:b5:8a:ea brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.85.41.126/21 brd 10.85.47.255 scope global noprefixroute ens192
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 2001:db8:1:0:250:56ff:feb5:8aea/64 scope global dynamic noprefixroute
    valid_lft 86386sec preferred_lft 14386sec
    inet6 fe80::250:56ff:feb5:8aea/64 scope link noprefixroute
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever


[root@vm1 ~]# iptables -L -v -n
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 3218K packets, 2240M bytes)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 719K packets, 48M bytes)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Information for VM2

```
[root@vm2 ~]# ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens192: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:50:56:b5:1d:0e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.85.41.127/21 brd 10.85.47.255 scope global noprefixroute ens192
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 2001:db8:1:0:250:56ff:feb5:1d0e/64 scope global dynamic noprefixroute
       valid_lft 86386sec preferred_lft 14386sec
    inet6 fe80::250:56ff:feb5:1d0e/64 scope link noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever


[root@vm2 ~]# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.85.40.1      0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 ens192
10.85.40.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.248.0   U     100    0        0 ens192
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0

[root@vm2 ~]# iptables -L -v -n
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 1119K packets, 1144M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 96234 packets, 6592K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination


[root@vm2 ~]# ip ne
10.85.40.2 dev ens192 lladdr 50:eb:1a:a7:39:2a STALE
10.85.41.126 dev ens192 lladdr 00:50:56:b5:8a:ea STALE
<SNIP>
```

What could be missing?

Comment: Please provide `ip addr` from both machines. Also, check firewall ``iptables -L -v -n``. I assume ping also doesn't work, you event don't see mac addresses in `arp` or `ip ne` output, right?

Comment: Edited question to provide all this info

Comment: Sounds like firewall on *VM1*.

Comment: and ``iptables -L -v -n`` on vm1?

Comment: added iptables info for vm1 in the question above

Comment: Does ESX have any builtin firewall? I think you should check it